# Oracle (19c) Created View has different datatype than underlying tables

Tags: oracle, view

We have a customer on Oracle 19C that when they create a View, the datatype is getting changed from CHAR(12) to VARCHAR.  This is a problem because the software tool we use to develop with has a model with the view and the datatype has to match.

I'm sure there are way better ways to write this, but this is what we delivered.  We are using a UNION ALL.  I verified the columns are aligned.  When we create it, the datatype is CHAR(12).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE VIEW "ACV_AC_DOSE_ACT" ("EXPID", "DATE_IN", "DATE_OUT", "RWP_NUMBER", "REV_NUMBER", "DOSE_RATE", "ACCESS_TIME", "DDE_EDEX", "EDEX_FLAG", "SDE_SK", "ENTRY_STATION", "EXIT_STATION", "DRD_ID", "WORK_STEP_SEQ_NO", "WORK_DOC", "ESCORT_FLAG", "ESCORTED_BY") AS 
  select a.expid, a.date_in, a.date_out, a.rwp_number, b.rev_number, a.dose_rate, a.access_time, 
    a.dde, null, a.sde_sk, a.entry_station, a.exit_station, a.drd_id, b.work_step_seq_no, 
    b.work_doc, b.escort_flag, b.escorted_by
    from acd_active a
    LEFT JOIN acd_active_supl b 
    ON (a.expid = b.expid) and (a.date_in = b.date_in)
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
    FROM edd_mb_rca_active c
    WHERE c.expid = a.expid
    AND c.date_in = a.date_in
    )
UNION ALL
 select expid, date_in, date_out, rwp_number, rev_number, null, access_time, sum_of_edex, 'x',
        null, entry_station, exit_station, 'MB', work_step_seq_no, work_doc_no, escort_flag, 
        escorted_by
    from edd_mb_rca_active
```

We checked the character data set.  AL32UTF8 (same as what we have)
We are asking the customer to drop the view and recreate it (rather than doing a replace).
If there is no data in the second table, we asked them to drop and recreate it, and then to rebuild the view.  (Still waiting on answers)

Comment: I meant that when the VIEW is created the two CHAR(12) fields end us as a VARCHAR (not CHAR(12))

Comment: It would be helpful to post a reproducible test case.  Are the columns in question `char(12)` in both of the queries you are union all-ing together?

Comment: @JustinCave - that's the problem; we cannot reproduce it on our Oracle system.  Yes, both tables have CHAR(12).  We have since learned that their system is making all CHAR datatypes VARCHAR in the views.  80% sure they have some type of setting on their DB that is making this occur.